# PHP Get 2 data rows in single iteration

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I'm trying to get two data rows in single iteration:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_website_index")or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
//returns single row`
}
```

In a html table

2 data lines in single row

```
<tr>
    <td>data 1</td>  
    <td>data 2</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You should crack on then. Don't let us stop you.

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get all data into an array. Then compose that array multidimensional array. So you can push two rows in every single key something like that.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $data[] = $row;
}

$last_data = array();
$key = 0;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data);$i++) {
  if($i%2 == 0)
  {
    $key++;
  } 
  $last_data[$key][] = $data[$i]; 
}
```

Then you can iterate over html table.

```
<?php foreach ( $last_data as $key => $row) { ?>
<tr>
    <?php foreach ( $row as $k => $row1) { ?>
    <td> <?php echo $row1['field'] ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

( Suggestion Use mysqli_* instead of mysql_* for keep your code using deprecated extensions. )

Comment: I got it done. Thanks a lot for the help. It helped me a lot to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you wanted this, but try:

```
<tr>
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_website_index")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
?>
<td><?php echo $row['col'] ?></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - please don't use mysql_query and use PDO instead.
Secondly - You would never do it this way. There are ways in which one could achieve this using references (next()). But that's very bad. As such I propose something like this:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("select * from tbl_website_index");
$query->execute();
$data = array();

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
 $data[] = $row->fieldName;
}

$data = "<li>" . implode("</li><li>", $data) . "</li>";
print "<ul>" . $data . "</ul>";
```

That would achieve what you are trying to do. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Have to do some more home work related to this thanks